# Not able to write logs to AWS cloudwatch from ASP.Net application hosted on Windows Elastic Beanstalk machine using NLog

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, logging, nlog, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I created a new ASP.Net application and deployed on AWS Elastic Beanstalk machine using its deployment toolkit. 
Now I am trying to add a logging framework to the application. I am using NLog and wanted to write the logs to the AWS CloudWatch folder.

I have installed AWS.Logger.NLog package from NuGet and added an NLog.config file to my application with the sample Logger class as below.

```
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      throwExceptions="true">
  <targets>
    <target name="aws" type="AWSTarget" logGroup="NLog" region="us-east-1"/>
    <target name="logfile" xsi:type="Console" layout="${callsite} ${message}" />
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="logfile,aws" />
  </rules>
</nlog>

public class Logger
    {
        private static NLog.Logger logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
        public static void LogErrorMessage(String message)
        {
            logger.Error(message);
        }

        public static void LogInfoMessage(String message)
        {
            logger.Info(message);
        }
    }
```

When I run my application locally the sample log folder is successfully created and the messages are getting logged on CloudWatch. 
But after deploying the application on ElasticBeanstalk nothing is getting recorded on CW. Even the folder is also not getting created then.

Can somebody please help me out what I am missing over here.

Answer (score 0):

What if you include `<extensions>` ?

```
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      throwConfigExceptions="true">
  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.AWS.Logger" />
  </extensions>
  <targets>
    <target name="aws" type="AWSTarget" logGroup="NLog" region="us-east-1"/>
    <target name="logfile" xsi:type="Console" layout="${callsite} ${message}" />
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="logfile,aws" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```